# C++ connecting to MySql server Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, exception

After trawling the web for hours on end to run a program that using the [**MySql C++ connector**](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) library, I finally managed it. But all of a sudden, with no changes to the project's `Properties`, file paths/locations/names, I am now getting the exception of:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7278AF68 (msvcr90.dll) in MySqlTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x736F686C.

Which in `Release` mode occurs on the line:

```
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "localhost", "")
```

and in `Debug` mode on this line:

```
std::cout << res->getString("_message") << std::endl;
```

The only change I made was to try and `INSERT` a value into a table as a test. It didn't work, but when I tried to retrace my steps, the exception shown above started appearing.

**The code that I am using (that ran initially) is from the [MySql Usage Exmaple 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html):**

```
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << std::endl;
    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "localhost", "");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
        while (res->next()) {
            std::cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            std::cout << res->getString("_message") << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            std::cout << res->getString(1) << std::endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Anyone know what is the issue here? I've had 2 days worth of pain regarding trying to get this to work already...

Comment: You may want to post this to one of the MySQL forums.